# How to cross-compile Git for ARM?

Tags: git, cross-compiling, autoconf

Unfortunately, I am having difficulty cross-compiling Git for the ARMv6 architecture.

But before I begin describing the steps I've taken and commands I've entered, I should briefly describe the build environment:

- I am cross-compiling on Ubuntu 12.10 64-bit.
- The cross compiler is installed to `/home/my_name/cctoolchain` (this directory contains `bin/`, `lib/`, etc.).

I began by grabbing Git 1.8.2 from [here](http://git-core.googlecode.com/files/git-1.8.2.tar.gz). After extracting the directory I ran:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/home/my_name/cctoolchain/bin
```

I also ran `autoconf` to make sure that `./configure` was up to date. Then I invoked `./configure` as follows:

```
./configure --prefix=/home/my_name/git-arm --build=x86_64-linux-gnu
  --host=arm-linux-androideabi
```

This ran for a couple of seconds and then aborted with:

```
checking whether system succeeds to read fopen'ed directory...
configure: error: in `/home/my_name/git-1.8.2':
configure: error: cannot run test program while cross compiling
```

I cracked open `configure.ac` and removed lines 806-825, disabling the test. After doing that, I also had to remove lines 806-839 for a similar reason.

At this point, the `./configure` script was able to complete. I then excitedly ran `make` to build Git and after a few more moments, ran into this error:

```
fetch-pack.c: In function 'fetch_pack':
fetch-pack.c:928:16: error: 'struct stat' has no member named 'st_mtim'
make: *** [fetch-pack.o] Error 1
```

Somehow I get the feeling I'm "doing it wrong". This sounds like something that should be a lot easier than manually removing tests from `configure.ac`. What am I missing?

Comment: Thanks, your question helped me a lot! The command that finally worked for me was `CC=armv7l-timesys-linux-gnueabi-gcc CFLAGS="--sysroot=/home/mmes/projects/arm-cross-sdk/tags/0.1.8" LDFLAGS="--sysroot=/home/evadeflow/projects/arm-cross-sdk/tags/0.1.8" ./configure --prefix=/home/evadeflow/git-arm --build=i386-linux-gnu --host=armv7l-timesys-linux-gnueabi`. (The `--sysroot=` arg shouldn't be necessary for most people.) I also had to comment out some tests in `configure.ac` as you described (`ac_cv_fread_reads_directories` and `ac_cv_snprintf_returns_bogus`), and run `make configure` afterwards.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The macro that's failing is `ST_MTIME_NSEC` in `git-compat-util.h`. This macro is controlled by the macros `USE_NSEC`, `NO_NSEC` and `USE_ST_TIMESPEC`, which are provided on the build commandline or by `config.mak.uname`, not by configure.

It *should* be that if no options are provided, git doesn't attempt to use nanosecond timestamps (or `st_mtim`) at all, but it looks like a bug slipped through.

Try `make NO_NSEC=1` and see if that resolves your problem.

Comment: **It worked!** After providing the extra parameter to `make`, the troublesome file compiled and the rest of the application seems to be building (so far, anyway).

Comment: @NathanOsman Can you provide some binaries of ARM git on a site somewhere so I can download it without having to build? Would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

I just cross compiled to ARM for a more recent version of git, 2.28, and also ran into issues with tests that cannot run during a cross build.

Please note that I had previously built zlib for ARM and have it installed at `/opt/arm-zlib`, which appears in the paths below.

The incantation that worked for me, without touching sources, was:

```
./configure --build=i686-pc-linux-gnu --host=arm-linux NO_ICONV=true ac_cv_fread_reads_directories=true ac_cv_snprintf_returns_bogus=false

make LDFLAGS=-L/opt/arm-zlib/lib CFLAGS=-I/opt/arm-zlib/include NO_TCLTK=true NO_GETTEXT=true
```

NO_TCLTK disables the GUI, which I did not want.

The other definitions that I passed to `configure` and `make` were best guesses; I did not investigate what the best answer would be on my ARM platform.

Comment: this is gold. one thing i'd add is for --host to work, you need to either have gcc-arm-linux-gnueabihf installed (and then --host=arm-linux-gnueabihf will be matched to that compiler), or you can specify a compiler directly with CC=/path/to/gcc, eg. after downloading it from https://developer.arm.com/Tools%20and%20Software/GNU%20Toolchain
I'm not sure how a simple "arm-linux" worked, perhaps your system had a corresponding "arm-linux-gcc" binary available, but that could correspond to several more specific arm architectures yet.

Answer (score 0):

I found that `./configure` supports caching the results of checks into a file. If you create that file by hand to match the behavior of your desired target, you can influence how `./configure` runs (to an extent).

First, I ran `./configure --config-cache` to configure for my local system. This will populate the cache file `config.cache` with the right variables and in the right format.

I then copied out the relevant checks into `config.cache.android`, cleaned, and re-ran `./configure` with my modified cache.

```
./configure --config-cache
mv ./config.cache ../
git clean -d -f -x
grep ac_cv_fread_reads_directories ../config.cache > config.cache.android
./configure --cache-file=config.cache.android # ...
# ...
checking whether system succeeds to read fopen'ed directory... (cached) yes
# ...
```

To know which variables you need to grab, you need to check `configure.ac`. This particular cache variable refers to `fread` even though the API being tested is actually `fopen`.

```
AC_CACHE_CHECK([whether system succeeds to read fopen'ed directory],
 [ac_cv_fread_reads_directories],
[
AC_RUN_IFELSE(
        [AC_LANG_PROGRAM([AC_INCLUDES_DEFAULT],
                [[
                FILE *f = fopen(".", "r");
                return f != NULL;]])],
        [ac_cv_fread_reads_directories=no],
        [ac_cv_fread_reads_directories=yes])
])
```

If the author of the `configure.ac` didn't think to use `AC_CACHE_CHECK`, then you have to resort to blunter instruments.